# Permutations of Several Words

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

$1$. $4$ letter permutations of RANDALODDI

For no repeats, this is $7P4$. For $2$A's and no other repeats I get $1\cdot1\cdot6C2\cdot\frac{4!}{2!} = 180$. Similarly, for $2$D's and no other repeats I get $180$ again. For $2$A's and $2$D's I get $6$. Finally for $3$ D's I get $24$. In total, I get $1230$.

$2$. How many anagrams of $GREECE$ with no two E's are adjacent to each other.

I arranged the GRC first giving $3! = 6$. Now there are like $4$ gaps to place the E's but we only need to choose $3$ of them so that is $4C3$. We don't give a shit about the order of the E's as they are all the same so that would be $\frac{3!}{3!} = 1$. In total I get $6\cdot4C3 = 24$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @jorisperrenet Can you verify my solutions / tell me where I went wrong ?

Comment: Your solutions and working out seem correct to me (I even wrote a short program to very the answers).

Comment: @jorisperrenet Thank you : ) It's a pisstake because there are no solutions and I don't have confidence in myself so I have to keep coming here to verify